# Problem about $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1))\cong(\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{R})/(x^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

From Ravi Vakil's FOAG,
[image]

Regrading $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}[y]/(y^2+1)$ we can obtain the second "$\cong$". I want to know whether it holds for general case, like $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1))$ and $(\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}[x])/(x^2+1)$.

**Update**

By MarianoSuárez-Álvarez's hint, we can prove the general case as following.

Suppose $F/K$ is a extension of field, $A$ is a $K-$algebra, and $I$ is a ideal of $A$. We have exact sequence:
$$
0\to I\to A\to A/I\to 0.
$$
Tensoring with $F$, and using the fact that field extension is faithfully flat, we obtain a exact sequence:
$$
0\to I\otimes_KF\to A\otimes_KF\to (A/I)\otimes_KF\to0.
$$
This exact sequence implies that $(A/I)\otimes_KF\cong(A\otimes_KF)/(I\otimes_KF)$. To prove the general case above, let $A=K[x],I=(f)$. Hence it suffices to prove $(f)\otimes_KF\cong(f)^F$, where $(f)^F$ means the principle ideal of $F[x]$ that generated by $f$.
To prove this, we construct a isomorphism. Define
\begin{align}
\varphi: (f)\otimes_KF          &\to     (f)^F\\
         \sum_i g_if\otimes l_i &\mapsto \sum_i l_ig_if.
\end{align}
It is easy to verify that $\varphi$ is a $K$-homomorphism. It remains to show that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. Suppose $\varphi(\sum_i g_if\otimes l_i)=0$, then $\left(\sum_i l_ig_i\right)f=0$, hence
$$
\sum_i g_if\otimes l_i=\left(\sum_i g_i\otimes l_i\right)(f\otimes 1)=0.
$$
Suppose $h=(a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0)f\in(f)^F$, then
$$
\varphi\left(\sum_i x^if\otimes a_i\right)=h.
$$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ok, I get it. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share section 10.2(3), which is the result Vakil cites for this isomorphism?

Comment: @MarkSaving  Main result of 10.2(3) is $(k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/I)\otimes_k(k[y_1,\cdots,y_m]/J)\cong k[x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_m]/(I,J)$